# Nonlinear Hyperbolic PDEs: Known solutions

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-pde, testing

I would like to collect some test-problems for nonlinear hyperbolic PDEs (Euler Equations, Shallow Water Equations, Ideal MHD, Acoustic Perturbation, ...) for which analytical solutions are known.

A famous example of this is the [isentropic vortex advection by Shu](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19980007543) for the 2D Euler equations.
For the Euler equations, some more examples are also given in [Chapter 7.13 of this book](http://www.cfdbooks.com/).
In 1D, often also solutions (at least for Riemann problems) can be constructed. Examples of this include Burger's Equation and the [LWR traffic model](http://www.clawpack.org/riemann_book/html/Traffic_flow.html#Traffic-flow:-the-Lighthill-Whitham-Richards-model).

Comment: Might be better suited for Mathoverflow than Computational Science

Comment: Probably worth a try, I could also give Physics SE a shot.

Answer (score 2):

A large and important class of problems with known exact solutions is given by the 1D Riemann problem, consisting of piecewise constant initial data with two initial states.  For instance, [this book](http://www.clawpack.org/riemann_book/) (which I co-authored) provides many examples of exact solutions of Riemann problems.

More generally (and especially if you want *smooth* solutions, or solutions in multiple dimensions) you can use the [method of manufactured solutions](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/fluidsengineering/article/124/1/4/462791/Code-Verification-by-the-Method-of-Manufactured).  In this approach you simply choose the exact solution, substitute it into the PDE, and find out what boundary and initial conditions are required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Wikipedia page listing non-linear PDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nonlinear_partial_differential_equations). Quite a few of them have exact solutions (though they are not all hyperbolic).